# Can't access Exception property

Tags: c#

I am catching an `ArgumentException`, of which I want a specific property. When I put a breakpoint on the code where the `ArgumentException` is caught, I see that it has an `ErrorMessage` property:

[image]

But trying to access it gives this result:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: Interesting question / first screenshot. I assume the debugger adds some detail somehow, afaict from [the ArgumentException source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/argumentexception.cs) there is no `ErrorMessage` property on it...

Comment: Is it possible that the actual type of the exception is some kind of class that *inherits* from `ArgumentException`?

Comment: There is no ErrorMessage property in the class _System.ArgumentException_ Are you sure that you are talking of this exact class and not of some kind of derived class (also other properties don't belong to this class)

Comment: The first screenshot looks more like a `HttpWebResponse` than the actual exception.

Comment: My bad guys. While this displays as an ArgumentException, further inspection reveals it is a WebServiceException thrown by ServiceStack. I am going to talk to the guy responsible for that code to make it more clear what kind of exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the first screenshot you display the `HttpWebResponse` or similar object, while in the second screenshot you are working with the actual exception.

Exceptions have a `Message` property and not an `ErrorMessage`. Change the second code to `ex.Message` and it will work.

Comment: If I do that, the content of my error message will simply be "ArgumentException", while I want to tell the users only to upload jpg images.

Comment: No it won't, as `WebServiceException` most likely do not inherit `ArgumentException`. Thus, your catch block will not be invoked at all. Either change so that you catch `WebServiceException` and use `ErrorMessage`, or catch `ArgumentException` and use `Message` property.

Comment: You were correct, I figured this out a while ago. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that the first screenshot is NOT a stamp of the exceptions internals.
An `ArgumentException` has no "ArgumentException" message. This is absolutely sure.

What is the first screenshot referring to? I really don't know, but it seems some sort of service context, already updated with the relevant information.

What you are probably searching for, btw, is the `Message` property of the exception.